# ExtJS get old and new value using renderer

Tags: extjs

I have Grid with 4 columns. Out of 4 columns in one column I have used renderer function

```
renderer :function(value) {return Ext.String.format('<input type=text name="sm name " width=5px value={1}>', value, value)
```

Using row editor , I get the modified and old value but using this input box , Is it possible to get the modified value and old value?

Please suggest here.

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you want to show value from column in row editor?

Answer (score 1):

I got help for this,and the problem is solved now. Thanks for everything. I just want to tell you the solution as anybody else might require this. I have used

```
var Grid=Ext.getCmp("EquipmentPartBO_GridComponentId_GridID");
    var store=Grid.getStore();
    var editedRecords = Grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords();
```

and used cell editor as I was looking out for the value from the Grid's specific column.